# Whitelabel Error Page This application .... There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401). Unauthorized

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

When I run the application, it displays this error (error 401).
How fix this problem and thank's :

Whitelabel Error Page

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback. There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized,
>   status=401). Unauthorized

pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>app-back</artifactId>
    <name>app-back</name>
    <description>module app backend </description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <start-class>app.AppApplication</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <hibernate.core.version>5.4.2.Final</hibernate.core.version>
        <maven.war.plugin.version>3.2.0</maven.war.plugin.version>
        <jjwt.version>0.9.1</jjwt.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>


         <!-- Spring data JPA, default tomcat pool, exclude it -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>app</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>${maven.war.plugin.version}</version>
                 <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                    <warName>app</warName>
                 </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy-resources</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static/</outputDirectory >
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>../app-front/dist/app-front</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

WebSecurityConfig.java :

```
package app.auth;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] ACCEPTED_FILES = {"/*.html", "/*.css", "/*.js", "/*.jpg", "/*.png", "/*.ico", "/*.txt", "/*.svg", "/*.eot", "/*.woff2", "/*.ttf", "/*.woff"}; 
    @Autowired
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean("authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedEntryPoint() {
        return (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }

     @Override
      public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
          .ignoring()
             .antMatchers("/assets/**","/home/**");
      }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
        .csrf().disable().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/sign-in").permitAll()
        .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(ACCEPTED_FILES).permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/auth/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/object/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint())
        .and().apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider))
        .and().httpBasic().disable();
    }
}
```

Appl.java :

```
package myApp.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("app")
@EnableJpaRepositories("app.repositories")
@EntityScan( basePackages = {"app.entities"} )
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class RefMetierApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RefMetierApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(RefMetierApplication.class);
    }

}
```

and this method in userServiceImpl.java :

```
@Override
    public Map<String, String> login(appUser requestUser) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationTokenRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                requestUser.getUsername(), requestUser.getPassword());
        try {
            Authentication authentication = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationTokenRequest);
            SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
            securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
            appUser user = (appUser) authentication.getPrincipal();

            String token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(requestUser.getUsername(), user.getAuthorities());
            Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<>();
            model.put("username", requestUser.getUsername());
            model.put("token", token);
            if(user.hasRule(ParamsEnum.ROLE_ADMIN.getValue())) {
                model.put("rule", "ADMIN");
            }
            else {
                model.put("rule", "USER");
            }

            return model;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new BadCredentialsException(ParamsEnum.BAD_CREDENTIALS.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Comment: This means the API / endpoint you are calling, requires some role. Can you specify which endpoint are you calling?

Comment: @AmitB10, in class Appl.java ?, I did not understand

Comment: @ali Please mention the URL, for which, you were getting the issue !

Comment: @ali Have you setup a USER with ADMIN role ?

Answer (score 0):

You must not have setup ADMIN ROLE, for the User attempting request.

Comment: I have Admin Role, because the users in my application are 2, normal users and administrators

Comment: @ali Please put up that code also.. ill also try to debug at my end

Comment: here is the method of login in userService.java